# How to get data from resultset to a list in java from oracle without loop?

Tags: java, oracle

How to get data from resultset to a list in java from oracle without loop ?

Comment: You have to iterate over the results

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have to avoid a loop?

Comment: You might want to use Java 8 Streams to avoid the loop.  But at its very core something is looping.

Comment: if you read JDBC document you will find that can not avoid loop, if you use Mybatis or other framework, they just wrapper of loop

Comment: You can with a utility method which does the looping for you.

Comment: You could possibly do something with DB objects and table types that get retrieved into arrays, but that's likely to be complicated and depends on your data and queries anyway.

Comment: The loop is taking too much of resource for a million record. If there will be any method by which we don't have to iterate than it will definitely reduce the memory usage.

Comment: The loop itself is using too much resource? Or fetching is? What fetchsize do you have - maybe you're really seeing an effect of too many small DB fetches when they could be batched up much more efficiently? If you need all million records in memory then it doesn't really matter how you get them, that won't affect how much space each one uses up, right?

Comment: Fetching is not an issue the way we iterate is taking too much of time . resultSet.next().

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: Because formation of resultset object didn't take time but the iteration took   huge amount of time and the memory usage also took a giant leap.

Comment: The resultset object doesn't contain all the data though - it executes the query but doesn't pull data back, the actual rows of the result set are fetched in batches as you need them, via `next()`. That's why the fetch size is important. Surely you're expecting memory usage to leap if you're sticking a million items into your list?

Comment: Nice observation. Can you provide a solution to this issue ? M stuck for this reason.

Comment: Stuck with what? You don't have enough memory to hold all million items in the list? Do you really need to, and all at once? If so can you increase the JVM memory settings, and/or add memory to the machine? We have no idea what your application is doing, why it's loading the list, what it will do with it, or what your environment is, so it isn't clear what the real problem is, never mind what the solution might be. Sorry.

Comment: We can't have unlimited memory always. So we should always thing of memory optimisation. Leave alone what is the memory size,the moral of the question was to get a way we can make that while loop faster. Thanks for ur insights ,It will definitely help ..

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. The commonly used practise is to loop thus:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   int value = rs.getInteger(1);
}
```

etc. The only practical way *not* to loop is to accept you only have one row in your result set.

Frameworks such as Spring JDBC can call your class back for each result, which means you don't explicitly loop, but instead the framework is doing that for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Because formation of resultset object didn't take time but the iteration took huge amount of time and the memory usage also took a giant leap.

You're misunderstanding the mechanism. When you execute the query the statement is parsed, a cursor is opened, and the ResultSet object is returned; but that doesn't mean all of the data is returned immediately. (The default behaviour varies by database vendor, I believe, but I'm only talking about Oracle). That's why the `executeQuery` part can be very fast for what will ultimately be a huge result set.

The rows in the result set will be sent from the database to the driver in batches, based on the configured fetch size, which by default is 10. Those 10 rows are buffered by the driver, and each time you call `next()` a row is returned from the buffer; if the buffer is empty it will fetch the next 10 rows into the buffer and then return one to you.

Your loop isn't intrinsically slow, inefficient or memory-hungry; it's the batched fetches from the database to the buffer that are relatively slow, and you can improve the performance of that by adjusting the fetch size. That is a trade-off between network and memory utilisation - the higher the fetch size the more memory has to be allocated for that buffer, and setting it too big can also be detrimental, especially if you are already memory-constrained.

What you *don't* have is all one million rows sitting in your ResultSet object, with the loop duplicating them one-by-one into your List, which seems to be what your question is implying. Only a small number of rows exist in the ResultSet buffer at any time, so that does not keep consuming more and more memory as you loop.

The memory usage growth you see is from all the items you're adding to your List. If you really do need all million items in your List, and at the same time, then you have to have enough memory to accommodate them. That's in the Java side, not in the database, query or JDBC. If you have spare memory on your server you can change the JVM memory allocation, and if not you can add more physical memory first.

But you might want reconsider whether you actually do have to hold all of them at once, or whether you could - for example - process the items in batches, so you only have to hold a smaller subset at any time. It entirely depends on what you're doing with them though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring JDBC, eg `JdbcTemplate.queryForList(String sql, Object... args)` returns `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: This was not helpful since it gave heap size issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet resultset = null;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
int i = 1;
while (resultset.next()) {            
    arrayList.add(resultset.getString("col 1"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 1"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 2"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col n"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion like this?

```
private void getListFromRS(ResultSet rs, List res) {
  if (rs.next()) {
    res.add(rs.getObject(1));
    getListFromRS(rs, res);
  }
}
```

and call

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
getListFromRS(rs, list);
```